# Two different Categories of local Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, notifications

I created  two different functions that each create a new local notification.

```
   func scheduleLocalNotification() {
    // Create Notification Content
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    // Configure Notification Content
    notificationContent.title = "Notif 1"
    notificationContent.subtitle = "Local Notifications"
    notificationContent.body = "hellow worlds."

    // Set Category Identifier
    notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = Notification.Category.tutorial

    // Add Trigger
    let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false)

    // Create Notification Request
    let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "cocoacasts_local_notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)

    // Add Request to User Notification Center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Add Notification Request (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
        }
    }
}
func scheduleLocalNotification2() {
    // Create Notification Content
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    // Configure Notification Content
    notificationContent.title = "Notif 2"
    notificationContent.subtitle = "Local Notifications"
    notificationContent.body = "hellow world + snooze"

    // Set Category Identifier
    notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = Notification.Category.tutorial

    // Add Trigger
    let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false)

    // Create Notification Request
    let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "cocoacasts_local_notification", content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)

    // Add Request to User Notification Center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Add Notification Request (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
        }
    }
}
```

I want the first function to create a normal notification without any actions and the second to create a notification with action button. So I create the following function

```
func configureUserNotificationsCenter() {
    // Configure User Notification Center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    // Define Actions
    let actionReadLater = UNNotificationAction(identifier: Notification.Action.readLater, title: "Read Later", options: [])
    let actionShowDetails = UNNotificationAction(identifier: Notification.Action.showDetails, title: "Show Details", options: [.foreground])
    let actionUnsubscribe = UNNotificationAction(identifier: Notification.Action.unsubscribe, title: "Unsubscribe", options: [.destructive, .authenticationRequired])

    // Define Category
    let tutorialCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: Notification.Category.tutorial, actions: [actionReadLater, actionShowDetails, actionUnsubscribe], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    // Register Category
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([tutorialCategory])
}
```

I then call the configureUserNotificationsCenter in viewdidload but this causes all my notifications to have these action buttons. I want only the notifications  scheduled using the scheduleLocalNotifications2 function and the notifications with other functions should not have these action buttons. How do I go around making that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are using a `notificationContent.categoryIdentifier` of `Notification.Category.tutorial`.  This is the same category that you are specifying the buttons on, which is why it shows up for both.  You need to create a second category identifier for your notification with no buttons